# Is Geo-fencing with polygons and dynamic objects available on android?

Tags: android, polygons

I can't find any documentation on geo fencing, specifically geo-fencing with polygons and dynamic objects. Is this functionality available?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1):

Check out SimpleGEO at https://simplegeo.com